# Cosmo Calendar shows dates from other screen

Tags: android, calendar, calendarview

I am using ApplikeySolutions/CosmoCalendar to show customized calendar. I have implemented this calender view in two seperate fragments. Both have distint Ids. When I show connected days on FragmentA , and go to FragmentB, it also shows the data of FragmentA.
Means CalendarView is not clearing data.

Answer (score 1):

CalendarView is keeping data in a manager. We have to clear the old data while adding new data to the list.
Here is the way -> calendarView.connectedDaysManager.connectedDaysList.clear()